# localbitcoins API /buy-bitcoins-with-cash/ endpoint problem

Tags: python, api, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to get local advertisements from localbitcoins.com the [API endpoint](https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/#local-buy) is /buy-bitcoins-with-cash/{location_id}/{location_slug}/.json

Using the python library I go with this code:

```
from lbcapi3 import api
hmac_key = 'my public key'
hmac_secret = 'my secret key'
conn = api.hmac(hmac_key, hmac_secret)
cash_trades=conn.call('GET', '/buy-bitcoins-with-cash/4.7109886/-74.072092/').js
```

And I get this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-28-8ee0ec40da0f>", line 1, in <module>
    cash_trades=conn.call('GET', '/buy-bitcoins-with-cash/4.7109886/-74.072092/').json()

  File "C:\Users\Chuox\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Chuox\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\Chuox\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "C:\Users\Chuox\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Not sure if I'm using the wrong parameters for the endpoint, I'm trying to find a successful example with no luck.

Comment: The problem was that they remove buy-bitcoins-with-cash option from the site without even an announcement :-/

Answer (score 1):

I think the location id and slug are more like codes, for example you can do something like this:

"https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/gbp/c/bank-transfers/.json"

Comment: The problem was that they remove buy-bitcoins-with-cash option from the site without even an announcement :-/

Comment: Ok that makes sense